# How to make a name group in a formula for specific order in Cross Tab Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008, crosstab

I want to make a crosstab in crystal report,

I opted for the specific order to build groups and ignore the other group, it joins the print screen

[image]

from what I've noticed I have to put the name of the group hard, is there a solution to put the name of the group in formula, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I know there is no way to put formula in `specified order` scenario